# How to open port on wsl2 ubuntu of windows 11

Tags: networking, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, firewall

To test the network between Windows 11 localhost and WSL2 ubuntu on Windows 11, I install tomcat9 on WSL2 ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt install tomcat9 -y
$ sudo systemctl enable tomcat9
$ sudo systemctl start tomcat9
$ sudo systemctl status tomcat9
```

The installation works successfully. The `localhost:8080` connection on windows 11 web browser is successful without errors. This time I try to deploy Apache Flink service in WSL2 ubuntu on Windows 11. First I download Flink 1.18.1, unzip the Flink and make link with Flink-1.18.1

```
$ ln -s flink-1.18.1 flink
```

And I make the ubuntu service file

```
$ nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/flink.service
    
[Unit]
Description=Flink Service
    
[Service]
Type=forking
User=joseph
Group=joseph
ExecStart=/home/joseph/flink/bin/start-cluster.sh
ExecStop=/home/joseph/flink/bin/stop-cluster.sh
    
Restart=always
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The Flink service starts with no error.

```
$ sudo systemctl enable flink
$ sudo systemctl start flink
```

Finally I open the Flink default port 8081 on Ubuntu firewall.

```
$ sudo ufw allow 8081/tcp
```

But `http://localhost:8081` on Windows 11 web browser can not connect the Flink service on WSL2 ubuntu even if I can find the 8081 port is open like below,

```
$ netstat -tnl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I can not understand the connection failure from Flink on WSL2 ubuntu. The tomcat9 is installed on WSL2 ubuntu the same way and `localhost:8080` on Windows 11 brings no error. I need your advice desperately. Thanks!

Comment: Two questions.  (1) What's the error you are getting from attempting to connect from Windows, (2) Have you tried to connect from *inside* WSL with something like `curl`?

Comment: Also, is `ufw` really in play here?  Usually it isn't running (and doesn't have much purpose in running) under WSL.

Comment: I solved it. This issue is the matter of Flink configuration. I set 'rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0' in flink-conf.yaml file and it works successfully. Thanks any any.

Comment: Good to hear - Consider putting in a self-answer to the question if you think it might be useful to others in the future.  Thanks!